# Is Java 1.4 64 bit supported in Windows 7 (x64)?

Tags: java

Is Java 1.4 64 bit supported in Windows 7 (x64)?

I installed it and installer says it cannot be installed.

Comment: Is there a reason you wish to install an ancient Java version?

Comment: The question is what is supporting what? In the first place Windows 7 (x64) supports all software written for one of the previous x86 and x64 versions. Since there is an x86 version of Java 1.4 it is in principle supported. But there might be bugs or compatibility problems in practice. If such problems occur, Oracle won’t fix them. Not because they don’t support Windows 7 but because the don’t support Java 1.4 anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The earliest supported Java Development Kit supported in Windows 7 was SE 6.18.

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6_updates):

> No security fixes; Hotspot VM 16; support for Ubuntu 8.04 LTS Desktop Edition, SLES 11, Windows 7, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3, Firefox 3.6, VisualVM 1.2; updated Java DB; many performance improvements

Comment: Specifically, it looks like the entry for `Java SE 6 Update 18` is when Win7 support was officially added.

Comment: Yes, true. I'll update my answer. From the Wikipedia article:

'No security fixes; Hotspot VM 16; support for Ubuntu 8.04 LTS Desktop Edition, SLES 11, Windows 7, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3, Firefox 3.6, VisualVM 1.2; updated Java DB; many performance improvements'

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the 64 bits Windows version of JDK 1.4 offered on Sun's(now Oracle) website is for the Itanium architecture (filename suffix ia64).  The 64 bits processors produced by Intel that are most popular today use another architecture (filename suffix x64).

Binaries for an Itanium will not run on eg Xeon processors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JDK 1.7. Its only a way better for Win 7